# How to deploy vuejs + adonis-api only project on heroku?

Tags: heroku, vuejs2, adonis.js

First thing i am very new in Vue, adonis and heroku. so please tell me all the steps in answer

i have a project build in vuejs(frontend) and adonisjs api-only and i want to deploy this project on heroku with postgresql database.

What i am done till now:-

1). create a heroku account
2). create a project on heroku
3). upload frontend dist/ folder on heroku using these command

```
git add --all
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push heroku master
```

And my frontend run perfectly but i don't know how to deploy backend and how to create database
in heroku.

my working directories are

[image: working directory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy the back-end application you can do the same steps as you did for the other application.

Here's what's changing:

- Add database with heroku add-ons (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql)

  - ! When adding the add-on new heroku environment variables are created. (If they do not appear, see below)

### Interesting things to know:

To execute Adonis commands : `node ace <your_command>` (`node ace migration:run`)
[image: run console - heroku]

I advise you to use the heroku environment variables. Don't forget to add the variable `ENV_SILENT = true` to avoid errors because of the.env file.
[image: heroku variables]

Get connection db informations: (on your postgresql add-on):
[image: db credentials]

#### Some additional information

Personal project deployed on heroku (`.gitlab-ci.yml`) : https://gitlab.com/CrBast/website

Interesting article : https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-adonisjs-apps-to-heroku

*If my explanations are not clear, don't hesitate to tell me :)*

Comment: What are the changes require in config/database.js for postgresql database

Comment: my Procfile look like                                                                          
release: ENV_SILENT=true node ace migration:run --force
web: ENV_SILENT=true npm start    but then it give error when run command                                                                                                      RuntimeException: E_MISSING_ENV_KEY: Make sure to define environment variable APP_KEY.
> More details: https://err.sh/adonisjs/errors/E_MISSING_ENV_KEY

Comment: `What are the changes require in config/database.js for postgresql database`: nothing, just update your environement variables

Comment: `my Procfile look like release: ENV...`: make sure to have this variables (not SENDGRID_USERNAME+SENDGRID_USERNAME) : https://ibb.co/h1THvdS

Comment: `"bash: node: command not found" in run console of heroku`: What order did you execute? What result does this command give you `node -v`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203657/discussion-between-it-mail-and-crbast).